# Rails Association Challenge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Having some challenges, need to keep track of the courses an Employee have taken. This is what i have these tables so far

```
Course: course_id,name,category_of_course...#holds Course related details

Employee: employee_id, name...#holds Employee details

progress:course_id,employee_id, status ...#holds which course have been 
taken and by whom
```

in My Models, i have this relationships:

```
 Employee: has_many :courses
```

Please how do i populate a Select List with the Courses that an Employee have not taken(assuming after registering for a course, it's flagged as taken). Im using rails 3.0.9 with MySql.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to define

```
belongs_to :employee
belongs_to :course
```

(in your progress model)

You can then define

```
#Employee
has_many :progresses
has_many :courses, :through => :progresses

#Course
has_many :progresses
has_many :employees, :through => :progresses
```

The select list will be:

```
= form_for @something do |f|
  = f.select :course_id, Course.all.select{|x| not @employee.courses.include?(x)}.collect{|x|[x.name,x.id]} #Ideally this logic should reside in the model.
```

Comment: Thanks,tried this but got some error[undefined method `course_id' for #<Employee:0x6558c30>], changing the :course_id to :id gets the courses for me but they are all represented as #<Course:0x6558c30> in the Select List. This is the Generated [SQL](http://pastie.org/3458369)

Comment: Thanks once again, got the name issue Fixed(though had to use :id instead of :course_id as i still get the Undefined error....), but after "registering" for a course, it's still comes up in the Select list.When a course is registered for,i simply, insert the Course_id,employee_id to the progresses table,I know im doing something wrong, please could you point further in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like the relationships aren't defined the way I've mentioned. Check via the Rails console if you're able to see the course via `some_employee.courses`

Comment: Just did that,it returns the Course that employee has registered for as expected. Thanks for the time Probably as added info,i added my Course_id and Employee_id columns, after inserting some records into their tables and the PK on these tables is the default  rails id column.